# Перевести URLRequest в url, а потом в строку

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview, request

Инициализирую метод `func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool` Первым делом нужно из запроса вытащить url и перегнать в строку. Подскажите, как сделать? Под ябочные устройства только начал кодить.

Comment: Не уверен, но попробуйте примерно так request.url - для получения url и далее url.path для получения строки из url.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась, `let webUrl = request.url?.absoluteString`